# why zookeeper get high cpu when leap seconds comes?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have a zookeeper cluster, machines get a huge spike in CPU after leap seconds. The solution is to restart the machine. Anyone knows why? Seems mozilla meets this also. http://blog.mozilla.org/it/2012/06/30/mysql-and-the-leap-second-high-cpu-and-the-fix/

Comment: I think you can find more information [here](http://zookeeper-user.578899.n2.nabble.com/leap-second-excitement-td7577634.html).

Comment: @dln385: Drop that link into an answer -it needs upvotes ;)

Answer (score 1):

They're looking into it, but it appears to be a Linux bug, and not a ZooKeeper bug specifically. For now, [this thread from the ZooKeeper User mailing list](http://zookeeper-user.578899.n2.nabble.com/leap-second-excitement-td7577634.html) should provide you with the most up-to-date information.